# TV Detective who travels back in time to solve crime

Tags: story-identification, tv

A British television series from the mid/late 90s, where the protagonist is a detective (?) somehow able travel back in time a few days (perhaps a week?) to solve crimes. I *think* other characters were unaware of his time travels...

I remember one episode where, during his investigation in the past, he saw a colleague and slipped him a piece of paper with some lottery numbers to play. When he arrived back, the rest of the team were celebrating his win with "bubbly", it then transpired it wasn't actually "real" champagne, confused we find out that:

> his colleague had put down the numbers upside-down, somehow meaning he'd got four numbers (several hundred pounds) rather than all of them (several million).

*The premise sounds a lot like [Seven Days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Days_%28TV_series%29), though I **think** this programme was aired prior to that...*

Any ideas?

Comment: I did have flash back of seven days but that definitely wasn't british.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably the reasonably-forgettable [Crime Traveller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_Traveller), starring Chloë Annett (the second Kochanski from Red Dwarf) and Michael French (David Wicks from EastEnders).

The hook was that Chloë's missing father had invented a time machine in his London flat, and she and policeman Michael could use it to go back 24 hours to solve a mystery: but they then had to live through that period in the past, and be back at the flat at the moment they left, or be stuck forever in a time loop.

Comment: "reasonably-forgettable" bah!

Comment: I think we need an 'obscure-tv-show-identification' tag, given the number of these I seem to answer.